# Difference in results of KL divergence in DIT and Scipy.Stats

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate KL divergence in Python between 2 probability distributions.

First I use the lib [dit](http://dit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/measures/divergences/kullback_leibler_divergence.html)

```
from dit.divergences import kullback_leibler_divergence
p = dit.Distribution(['0', '1'], [3/4, 1/4])
q = dit.Distribution(['0', '1'], [1/2, 1/2])
kullback_leibler_divergence(p, q)
```

This returns `0.1887`

If I try to do the same using [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html)

```
from scipy.stats import entropy
p = [3/4, 1/4]
q = [1/2, 1/2]
entropy(p,q)
```

This returns `0.1308`

Why is the difference in results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logarithm bases are different. 
dit uses log_2 whereas scipy uses log_e.